# How do I know if Monero is running on Putty?

Tags: monerod

When I run Monero, it seems to be eating up my CPU space. How do I run it on a VPS? I've got a VPS, and I installed PuTTY.  What is next?

Answer (score 4):

Once you have PuTTY open and you have an SSH connection to your VPN server try the following commands:

#### Download the current Monero Core binaries

`wget https://downloads.getmonero.org/linux64`

#### Make a directory and extract the files

```
mkdir monero
tar -xjvf linux64 -C monero
```

#### Keep monerod running forever by using Linux Screen

`screen -S myFullNode`

> This ensures that when you close the PuTTY SSH connection the node will continue to run. There is an optional flag for monerod `--detach` but I don't use this.
>
> It should be installed already, if not `yum install screen`

#### Launch the daemon

```
cd monero
./monerod
```

#### Return to main terminal to run your wallet or w/e

`Ctrl` + `a` + `d`

```
cd monero
./monero-wallet-cli
```

> Make a new wallet, open an existing wallet or w/e

#### To view your monerod node

`screen -r myFullNode`

Comment: Thank you Miles.  I am up and running and block chain is syncing.  The next thing I need to do is configure wallet, which you have shown me how to do.  Should I wait for sync to complete prior to addressing wallet?

Comment: No need for screen - you can use the --detach option

Answer (score 2):

Edited, now that I understand your question better:

You will have high CPU usage and high I/O traffic as `monerod` syncs.  It has to download the entire blockchain and build the lmdb database.  While it's running, type "status" and hit Enter, to see how far along the sync is.  Once it has synced up, you may find the the VPS is unnecessary.

If you want to host your node on a VPS, it may be a headache, if it's below-spec.  Depending on the VPS, it could take several days before you're fully synced.  If your RAM is too low, you won't be able to build `monerod` at all.  But if you download/build `monerod` and get it running, then that will take care of most of your headaches.  Once you're synced, the resource requirements drop way down, as mentioned already.

As mentioned in another answer, if you will be SSH'ing into your session, you can use `screen`, or I prefer `tmux` (since it's easier to search for how to do things with it). With a `tmux` window/session open, you'll run `monerod`.  Once it's running, hit ^B (control+b), d, to detach.  When you want to view how `monerod` is doing, enter `tmux attach`, and the session will restore. Control+b, then d, to detach again.

Comment: Thank you.  But I am still unsure as to whether or not I am using the VPS at all?  How can I tell?  As you can tell, I have never uses a VPS...

Comment: I'm reading about how to tunnel ssh putty.  Hopefully I can figure it out...

Comment: See the edits to your question and to my answer.  Also, there is another good answer here to guide you.

Comment: Thanks so much, I am up and running using vps via interserver.  It appears to be syncing to block chain.  Next step will be configuring wallet...